# Notification for new questions is missing on the main site

Tags: feature-request, live-refresh

I try to give an answer (or at least clarify) as many questions as I can, but I'm not going to refresh the new questions page constantly.

On many other Stack Exchange sites, including the Stack Overflow meta site, there is a notification on my tab title for when there is a new question so I know to visit the page:

[image: Tab Notification] *In tab title `(1)`*

And once I visit the page, there is this button I can click to refresh automatically:

[image: In Site Notification]

Is it intentional that these features are not present on the main Stack Overflow site?

Comment: Not saying you do that... but quality is more important than quantity. Reading "I try to answer as many questions as I can" makes me question if the appropriate time is put into each answer to be complete, clear, and of high quality...

Comment: @Patrice I put a lot of effort into each answer. If a question is just like a simple typo though, I might not explain things as much.

Comment: fair enough. As I said, didn't mean to say you do that. Just wanted to be sure you take the time to make your posts worth of the site :). Happy to see you do. Although if a question is a simple typo, you should comment that it is then flag to close as off-topic :)

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå except I see them on meta (same reputation as main site) and I am above 30 rep.

Comment: There is no websocket connected on the site wide new question page for reasons of performance. You can however get websocket notificatons on the new tab for a tag, for example [Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)

Comment: see [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox) on MSE, kindly provided by Shadow Wizard.

Comment: Yup, if anything activity only raised since then, so I don't think this feature request is feasible.

Comment: @rene that's helpful. thank you.